# Question ... I am studying the $ .post () method, however, I only see examples with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql

Good night guys!

I'm new to programming and now I'm studying the $ .post () method and I have a few questions:

1 ° - Why should I use the $ .post () method?

2 ° - In all the examples I see, they always use the $ .post () method to send something to PHP ... Is it possible to send something other than PHP? If so, could you give me examples using only JQUERY, HTML, mysql and JSON? (that I'm studying)

Note: I'm a beginner.

Comment: Sending is the same. It's receiving on the Server that's different, depending on your Server Language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.post() is a jQuery method that allows you to send a request to a server (typically) with data that can be processed by the server and sent back.

PHP is a programming language that can run in a server, accept the $.post() request, and process the request.

$.post(), the jQuery method, is used in the "front-end" of web apps. The front-end is the part the user uses. So, a typical example of the use of a $.post() request would be a user on a social media app adding new images to their profile. The image is transformed into data (bytes) and sent from the users computer to the server with the $.post() method.

That's where PHP comes in. PHP will receive the data bytes and save it to the users profile. All the magic of making sure we have the right user and pulling up their info then adding the new image to their profile actually happens here. At the end of it, typically a "success" or "error" response is sent. For reference, when you get a 404 error or a 500 error, that is where the error came from. A server.

The front-end of web applications is very limited. It only has JavaScript, jQuery (which is just a sub-set of JavaScript), HTML5, CSS3, and some altered versions of these.

The back end, the server that handles all the requests and sends all the data back, can be done in a plethora of different languages. PHP is an older language but it is still actively updated and still used in a lot of legacy apps. We now have Node.js, Java, Python, etc. A lot of different languages to write a back end.

Hopefully this clears some things up for you. Please feel free to ask me questions in the comment section or send me a message if you don't have enough reputation to comment yet (don't know the numbers lol).

Comment: Could you please provide me with code as an example with the backend in node.JS? for me to study. Thanks for answer

Comment: Sure. It'll be a bit but I'll get to it. Is there a reason other than that you did not up vote my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the forum ... I didn't know where to accept the answer;)

Comment: No prob :) There are up and down arrows next to a number directly on the left of the answer (also next to your question). Click up to up-vote it (consider it an acceptable answer) or click down to say that you don't feel the answer helped/was relevant.

Comment: Also. you'll see your question is closed. This is because what you're looking for is explained in documentation produced by the maintainers of the code you use. Both jQuery and PHP have extensive documentation publicly available. Here is jQuery's official guide to the $.post() method: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/. This link: https://api.jquery.com/ is the main page which has on it the complete documentation for the entire jQuery library. Here's PHP's official docs: https://www.php.net/docs.php

Comment: Lastly, I'll say, both jQuery and PHP are more along the lines of legacy technology now. Although they are still used and relevant, they are both far from in-demand or considered hot tech right now. This is especially true for jQuery with the emergence of the revolutionary modularity approach to websites with tools like React and Angular. I'm a huge fan of React and I would highly recommend it. React is also front-end, so it can communicate with servers using any other back-end language as well. I've built a lot of React apps with Node.js and it's relatively easy.

Comment: Oh I forgot that you can actually accept the answer. I'm still kinda new myself lol. Thank you!